# AngularJS Displaying Table Row on expansion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to show a more detailed summary of a row when a user clicks on the "+" icon on the row. I got it to work when I used an  tag but when I modified it to an  tag, the javascript would not kick in.

Here's what I have:

```
<table class="table" ng-repeat="lineItem in order.OrderLineItems">
                    <tbody >
                        <tr >
                            <td class="col-md-3"><a ng-hide="!lineItem.OrderLineItemModifiers.length " class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"  ng-model=show></a> <b>Item</b></td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">{{lineItem.Name}}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">{{lineItem.Quantity}}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">{{lineItem.TotalPrice}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="modifiers in lineItem.OrderLineItemModifiers" ng-show="show">
                            <td class="col-md-3"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-3 ordermodifier">{{modifiers.Name}}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3"></td>
                            <td class="col-md-3 ">{{modifiers.TotalPrice}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div><b>Total Amount: {{order.TotalAmount}}</b></div>
```

And in the Javascript file:

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, order) {
    $scope.toggleDetail = function ($index) {
        $scope.activePosition = $scope.activePosition == $index ? -1 : $index;
    };
});
```

What I am confused about is why would this work if I used an  tag instead of an  ? With the current code above, I would click on the "+" and it would not expand the row to show the modifier rows

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is confusing. "I used an tag instead of an ? " what does that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td class="col-md-3"><a ng-hide="lineItem.OrderLineItemModifiers.length !== 0 " class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"  ng-model=show></a> <b>Item</b></td>
```

try this. not sure what problem you had.